# Anonymous target audience in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, anonymous, target-audience

The biggest problem I have faced so far in sharepoint, is to be able to make a certain webparts invisible or hide if the user is not logged in, basically to be able to make an audience for anonymous user.
If anyone knows how to do that, please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to do that out of the box is to wrap the complete Web Part Zone in a SPSecurityTrimmedControl.
Another thing you could try is to create Control Adapter for every single Web Part type and then implement the display logic in there. Please notice though, that this approach has some limitations. The most important is that all Control Adapters will be applied to every single Web Part in the given Web Application of the given type.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick I use is to hide the web part in your CSS (either your master CSS or another web part), and then use ANOTHER web part - this time targeted to authenticated users - that overrides the initial CSS, making the content visible. I wouldn't recommend it for secure content, since the web part is still being rendered at the client, but if you're going for UI elements, this works perfectly.